# Oracle Compound Trigger issue

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, triggers

(Using Oracle 11G)

So I have this `UPDATE` trigger, its job is to get a single row from my ccv_p `TABLE` and insert it into my oldRecord `RECORD` in a before each statement (It's a compound trigger), then after that, I'd like to get the `PRC_ID` of that row through oldRecord in an after each row statement...doesn't seem to be working though, it doesn't insert anything into my test table. Through some debugging i've found out that my problem lies with the select statement, but i'm not really too experienced in Oracle...Any thoughts? Here's some important snippets of code:

```
oldRecord CCV_P%ROWTYPE;

select ccv_p.* into oldRecord from ccv_p inner join parcel on ccv_p.prc_id = parcel.prc_id where ccv_p.PRC_ID = :new.PRC_ID;

insert into TEST$_TABLE (TEST$_TABLE.num) VALUES (oldRecord.PRC_ID);
```

Comment: Hi, 
It would be useful if you would add some info like the create trigger statement.

Answer (score 0):

Is the trigger defined for the CCV_P table?
in that case, you don't need to query the table. What you probably want to do is:

1) populate your recordtype

```
my_rec.PRC_ID := :old.PRC_ID;
```

2) Insert into your table

```
insert into TEST$_TABLE (TEST$_TABLE.num) VALUES (:old.PRC_ID);
```

This will of course not work for Inserts

Comment: Thanks, the answer was very helpful (sorry for the late reply btw! was confused on how to reply on this website)